# How to store the element of vectors to a specific position of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Problem:

I have a list of vectors of the same length. I would like to convert these vectors to lower triangular matrices. However, each element of each vector will take a specific position at these matrices.

Please note that my original matrix is very complicated and strongly based on a `for` loop. Hence, I need to solve this problem to use `for` loop.

Example:

Assume that I have the list `X` with `10` vectors, i.e,

```
X <- list(x1=c(1:3), x2=(2:4), x3=c(4:2), x4=c(5:7), x5=c(12,34,54), 
          x6=c(3:5), x7=c(2:4), x8=c(3,4,5), x9=c(44,56,7), x10=c(34,5,4))
```

Each vector contains `3` elements. Then, I need to assign a number to these vectors, `x=c(1:10)`. `1` refers to `x1`, `2` to `x2` and so on.

Then, I need to convert `x` to a lower triangular matrix, i.e,

```
x <- c(1:10)
M <- matrix(0,5,5)
M[lower.tri(M, diag=FALSE)] <- x

M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    5    0    0    0
[4,]    3    6    8    0    0
[5,]    *4*    *7*    9   10    0
```

`4`, `7`, `9` and all other entries of `M` are called the position of each vector of `X`. For example, *4* refers to `x4`, *7* refers to `x7` and *9* refers to `x9` and so on for other vectors. Hence, the position of `x4` is the entire `4` at `[5,1]` at `M`.

Now:

- I need to store the element of each vector at the position of its vector in `M`. In other words, each element of each vector is stored based on the number of the vector of this element. For example, `54` belongs to vector `5`, hence, its position is `5`.

For example, the element of vector `x4` are `5, 6, and 7`. Then, I need to store them in three different lower triangular matrices each element at its position, i.e,

```
> X_new[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0    0    0    0    0
[2,]  0      0    0    0    0
[3,]  0.0    0    0    0    0
[4,]  0.0    0    0    0    0
[5,]  5      0    0    0    0


X_new[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[2,] 0       0    0    0    0
[3,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[4,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[5,] 6       0    0    0    0
> 



X_new[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[2,] 0       0    0    0    0
[3,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[4,] 0.00    0    0    0    0
[5,] 7       0    0    0    0
```

Hence, the elements of the vector `x4` take the same position of `4` at the lower triangular matrix `M`. The same for all other vectors.

For this, I Must use for loop (as my original function uses for loop).

`k = 5, 4, 3, 2` number of the rows. Then, `i= 4, 3, 2, 1` entire of each row.

```
for(k in 5:2){ 
    for(i in 1:(k-1)){ 
        X_new[k,i] <- X[[i]]
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do this, please?

Comment: In the description, it says `Then, each element of each vector will be stored in its position`  if you have values like `54`, then on a 5x5 matrix, that position is not there

Comment: @akrun `54` belongs to vector `5`. So its position is number `5`.

Comment: In that case, isn't it `m1 <- do.call(rbind, X[4:5]); lapply(split(m1, col(m1)), function(x) {M <- matrix(0, 5, 5);  M[c(4, 5)] <- x; M})`

Comment: @akrun your answer is very clever. However, by the position, I meant the number at the matrix `M`. Not the `[4,]`. I meant number `4`. For example, `4` is at `[5,1]` of `M`. I will make it clear. Sorry. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, was away on a call

Comment: The one you showed as output can be got with `lapply(X$x4, function(x) {M <- matrix(0, 5, 5); M[5, 1] <- x; M })`, but I am confused because `x4` is the 4th element of the `list`.  Why the elements are placed at `5, 1`

Comment: Because my function converts the list to a lower triangular matrix from top to bottom.

Comment: I really need a `for` loop.

Comment: It is still not clear.  try `lst <- vector('list', 4);
> for(i in  1:4) {for(j in seq_along(X[[i]])) {M <- matrix(0, 5, 5); M[i, 1] <- X[[i]][j]; lst[[i]] <- M}}`

Comment: Based on your code `out <- setNames(vector('list', 4), 5:2);
 for(k in 5:2){ for(i in 1:(k-1)) {M <- matrix(0, 5, 5); M[i, 1] <- X[[k]][i]; out[[as.character(k)]][[i]] <- M}}`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `lapply`

```
lapply(X[4:6], function(x) {
         M <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
         M[lower.tri(M, diag = TRUE)] <- x
     M
    })
```

---

If we need a `for` loop,

```
for(i in 4:6) {
    tmp <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
    tmp[lower.tri(tmp, diag = TRUE)] <- x
    X[[i]] <- tmp
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clever and fast help. I edit my question where I really need to use a `for` loop. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciated your help and I am really so sorry. I need to use `for (k in 5:2)` for the number of the row. Then, `for (i in 1:(k-1))` for each entire of each row. Sorry, but this is required from my very complicated original function.

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for your help. I tried the first part of the answer, but it did not place each element of each vector to its corresponding position. For example, the vector `x4=c(5,6,7)` which should be placed at the same position of number `4`. That is, they should be placed at row 5, and column 1. `[5,1]`.

Comment: @Maryalm It is not very clear to me.  Do you need `m1 <- do.call(rbind, X[4:5]); lapply(split(m1, col(m1)), function(x) {M <- matrix(0, 5, 5); i1 <- lower.tri(M, diag = FALSE); M[i1] <- x; M})`

Comment: Sorry for not be clear in my question. I will edit it right now to be much more clear. and also I will try your help.